# Folder Encryption in a network

Tags: windows-7, networking, encryption, lan

I am using Windows 7 and I want to put a password in my folder in a LAN. 
Example: The \192.168.1.1 address is the Server of File sharing in a LAN (in my case). So all of the PC's that are connected to the LAN will access to this address when they need to copy or paste a file. Now, I want some of the folders to be encrypted. The folders are visible but it needs a password before you can open or access to it. I don't want to compress the files I just want a folder that requests for a password when a user opens it. Axcrypt seems similar but the problem is it only encrypts the content of the folder and not the folder. Please help!

Comment: Why does it need to be encrypted if you can use acl's to allow access to only those who need access?

Comment: Because that is what my professor want to do..